# Windows: Is it possible to take a screenshot (capture image screen) during UAC Administrator Elevation Prompt?

Tags: windows-7, uac, screenshot

This is mostly out of curiosity, but I think it could be useful some day:

As long as the **UAC Administrator Elevation Prompt** in Windows (Vista and laters) is [supposed](http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/100/understanding-windows-at-a-deeper-level-sessions-window-stations-and-desktops) to be done in a **different desktop**, the keypressing <kbd>PrtScreen</kbd> does not copy the **screen contents to the clipboard**, as it always does on normal desktops.

Is there any **workaround** for this?

Comment: No. Technically, the UAC screen is a different user session with a different instance of the clipboard. I'm pretty sure that if you could paste before dismissing the UAC prompt, it would work, but never encountered a way to do that.

Comment: Since when does `PrnScreen` not capture the screen if UAC is enabled, because I can tell you, from experience that isn't the case. Your single massive statement is difficult to under to be frank.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesnt work when UAC is *enabled*, but when it is *prompting* (the yes/no dialog, or the prompt for another accounts credentials). try it yourself. launch a program as admin, and when the UAC propmt appears, hit prntscrn. then click yes or no to dismiss the prompt, and attempt to paste. your printscreen contents will not be in the clipboard. UAC prompts run in an isolated desktop, so that malware can't manipulate the mouse to automatically click 'yes'.

Comment: op, you can try this for disabling the secure session, but Its probably not a good idea: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/make-user-account-control-uac-stop-blacking-out-the-screen-in-windows-vista/

Comment: @FrankThomas: AFAIK, it is the same _session_, but a different _desktop_.

Comment: @grawity, that is likely the case. unfourtunatly, desktop or session, they don't share a clipboard with the interactive users desktop process.

Comment: @FrankThomas: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096(v=vs.85).aspx, clipboards are per-window-station and each session has exactly one interactive window-station (WinSta0), so it must be that all desktops for that session, both the regular one and the secure ones, share the same clipboard.

Comment: are you able to snag a prntscrn while the UAC Yes/No dialog is displaying? I cannot, unless I disable the "secure desktop".

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a duplicate topic, there's one thing that no one has mentioned yet.

If you install TeamViewer on your pc, and you have rebooted your pc, teamviewer will then be able to access the UAC prompt. From another pc that is using teamviewer, you can make a screenshot of your whole desktop while teamviewer is visible but does not have focus, and you'll have a screenshot of the UAC prompt.